# Android alert Dialog not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
```

Can anyone tell me the problem with this code .It gives the below exception:

11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andoroid.dialog/com.andoroid.dialog.AlertDialogTestActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.andoroid.dialog.AlertDialogTestActivity.createDialog(AlertDialogTestActivity.java:48)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.andoroid.dialog.AlertDialogTestActivity.onCreate(AlertDialogTestActivity.java:22)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-06 11:44:20.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea:

1) use current activity instead of `mContext = getApplicationContext();` for example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**this** refers to your activity if you are writing code in it.

2) clear your project

Comment: thanx alot mate it worked !!! can you tell me the reason what was wrong in using applicationContext.

Comment: public Context getApplicationContext () 
Since: API Level 1 
Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, if you want a custom Dialog there is no need to inflate the views and use an AlertDialog.Builder.

Instead, you can do it like this:

```
Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
TextView text = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

customDialog.show();
```

You can see an example of this in the Android Dev Guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog