# How do i get this android custom dialog to appear(inflate)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd be very grateful for explicit instruction. This is from a google android dev tutorial but, I can't find a way to display(inflate) it. alertDialog.show() causes the program to crash on the emulator.

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
    mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

at the end use:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I've tried that and just did again. The emulator says the program quits unexpectedly. Logcat is failing at the moment

Comment: What's the response you're getting from logcat?

Comment: I couldn't get the text to fit here. Here the gist link: https://gist.github.com/1673471

Comment: try this: `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);`

Comment: That didn't work either. However, I have found a solution that I will post in a second.

Comment: Stack won't let me answer my post for another 7 hours. I used this [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8025596/465001). The dialog was just an introductory popup for my app. Will this fix casue me any problems down the road?

Comment: using `getBaseContext()` or referencing to your activity via `this` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most easy and more customizable way to proceed is by inflating an DialogFragment.

You'd do the following in the activity:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
DialogFragment dfrag = new CustomDFrag();
dfrag.show(ft,"dialog");
```

And then create the class CustomDFrag that extends DialogFragment. Then you override onCreateDialog and use what you've done so far but now with a custom layout:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null);

            //this is how you'd get a view from the inflated layout
    data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.evo_addhist_data); 
    data.setText("lol");


            //tell the builder that you wan't that inflated layout to show
            // and then set the button (negative/positive in this case) if you want
    builder.setView(
            view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

ps.: i've recomended this because i think it's better when not dealing only with a textview.